# How can i plot random images loaded with ImageDataGenerator?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

I would like to plot random image samples loaded into ImageDataGenrator,
how can i do it??

I already imported the module, but i don't know how to get the images

```
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255)
train = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(PATH, target_size = (IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE), batch_size = K, class_mode = None)

plt.imshow(?)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The generator will yields a tuple (images, labels), where images has shape (batch_size, image_size[0], image_size[1], num_channels). See code below:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from IPython.core.display import display, HTML

image_size=224
batch_size=10
source_dir=r'c:\temp\birds\test'
save_dir=r'c:\temp\birds\storage'
rand_seed=123
# if you want to save the images set save_dir to a directory and save_formay to the format you want otherwise leave these values as None
test_gen=ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255).flow_from_directory(source_dir,
                target_size=(image_size, image_size), batch_size=batch_size, color_mode='rgb',
                seed=rand_seed, shuffle=False, save_to_dir=save_dir,save_format="png" )
batch=next(test_gen)  # returns the next batch of images and labels 
print(batch[0].shape) # batch[0] is the images, batch[1] are the labels
img=batch[0][0]   # this is the first image  batch[0][1] would be the next image
print (img.shape)
plt.imshow(img)   # shows the first image

You can set shuffle=True to get the images in random order
```

Answer (score 1):

One way I know to do it is to convert the TensorFlow generator to a python generator and then call next on it.

```
train_iter = iter(train)
batch = next(train_iter)
```

I have done this for other more generic Tensorflow Dataset objects so I assume it would work here.