# Plot random image from the ImageDataGenerator

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to plot an image according to the generated random number from ImageDataGenerator and I was not able to plot the image due to errors.

```
test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    preprocessing_function=preprocess_input)

test_gen = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(test_path,
                                            target_size = (SIZE, SIZE),
                                            batch_size = 32, shuffle=False )    

i = random.randint(0,800)
    
batch=next(test_gen)  
print(batch[0].shape) 
img=batch[0][i]   
print (img.shape)
plt.imshow(img)
```

I've tried the solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62944529/how-can-i-plot-random-images-loaded-with-imagedatagenerator), which is used above, however it gives me error when the randomly generated number is high.

```
IndexError: index 523 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 32
```

**Note:**

- I don't want the image to be plotted randomly by changing the
  `shuffle=True`, I want to plot the image according to the randomly generated number.
- I don't want to change the range of the generating random number and
  it needs to be the given value.(0,800)

Answer (score 0):

You are using a batch size of 32.

So, when you are generating a random number with
`i = random.randint(0,800)`,
you are generating an integer between [0,800], which exceeded your batch of images (This is what the error said basically, you generated 523 and it is out of bounds for the batch where there are only 32 images)

Try to write
`i = random.randint(0,31)`

Comment: I understand that, I need to get the image according to the generated random number in the given range (0,800), reducing the range is not a fix for this issue.

Comment: If you absolutely have to use i = random.randint(0,800), you have to produce at least 801 images in the batch for you to access. How could one access image #532 if there are only 32 images in the batch? If you don't want to change the given range, you could increase the batch size to 801